# Connect an email on Opp to a Contact

Tags: apex-email-service, emailmessage

I have 2 questions:

1) I am writing an email service apex class which creates an email on Opportunity as an activity and attaches files to it. I need this email to be related to contacts from the related Account. I was trying to create a new EmailMessageRelation to bind the email to Contact using **RelationId**  and tried to test it but I was getting internal salesforce errors all the time.

Is there a way to bind an email on Opportunity to a Contact?

2) Is it possible to create an email as an activity on Lead? I tried using RelatedToId when creating an EmailMessage but this field supports neither Lead nor Contact objects.

Comment: The email will be related to the contact it is sent to.  Are you trying to relate it to a contact that is not the recipient?

Comment: I'm trying to save an EmailMessage as draft. When specifying a contact and its email, a task(activity) is not created. I need an activity to be linked to the EmailMessage. Even though when I create an emailmessage as draft with an Opp as relatedId, a task is created